# Deploy asp net core 3.1 app into azure throught ftp

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, deployment, ftps

I am trying to deploy simple dotnet application (dotnet new webapi) into azure, through the FTPS,
But I always see the the same picture by the azure's URL:
[image]

The configuration/General settings:

- Stack: .NET Core
- Major version: 3.1
- Minor version 3.1.0
- Startup Command: dotnet < name >.dll

I have tried to publish through Visual Studio with FTP deployment with profile ("Get publish profile" button in the overview). Also I have tried to send all files manually through FTPS. The path i took from publish profile file.

Note: I switched stack to PHP and passed index.html through the FTPS manually - it worked.

Is there step by step guide, to deploy asp net core app through FTPS?

Comment: You have to click on `deployment center` then [follow these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp)

Comment: I was doing exact these steps, the problem is not resolved :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `web.config` file under your website folder:

[image]

The content of `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CoreWebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Note to change `CoreWebApplication.dll` to your own dll file.

Then, use FTP to upload all files to Azure Web App `site\wwwroot\` folder:

[image]

Finally, restart your web app to check if your .NET Core application was successfully deployed.

Comment: The web config is already there, the content is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DotnetTestAuth.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: guid-->

Comment: I tried several times here, every time I could get a success. Every time I uploaded files via FTP, and restart the web app, it just worked.

Comment: @JackJia I've posted a question here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197229/the-development-environment-shouldnt-be-enabled-for-deployed-applications-dotn shows me, "The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications."

Comment: @JackJia i've followed the https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/07/09/deploying-asp-net-core-azure-app-service-ftp/ and used the "bin\Release\publish" and uploaded the project still it shows me. "The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications."